# Experience Profile page API for pattern matches throws object reference not set error

Tags: experience-profile

I have recently created profiles and applied them to some of my pages. However, now when I go into Experience Profile for contacts that have visited a page that has the profile applied I get the following.

The API that is called:
`http://mydomain/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/631499c3-7f1e-0100-0000-059b107847ad/intel/best-pattern-matches?&pageSize=3&pageNumber=1`

Response:
`{"Message":"An error occurred. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

My Profile has 5 keys each has a max value of 10. I used a profile card to apply the profile to a content item.

I am getting this error in my local development environment where I am running CD in live mode.

Here is the stack trace from the log file.

```
16140 21:14:03 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Cintel
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.ReportingServerDatasource.VisitPatternScores.PrepareProfileKeyMapping.GetProfileKeyItems(Item profile)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.ReportingServerDatasource.VisitPatternScores.PrepareProfileKeyMapping.Process(ReportProcessorArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternToOneProfile(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataRow profileRow)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternsToResultTable(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataTable resultTable)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.Process(ReportProcessorArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.IntelController.Get(ViewParameters viewParams, Guid contactId, String viewId, String id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok as soon as I posted this I realized I should check it's published state of the profile. I thought I had published it but, as it turns out, I had not. As soon as I published the profile all was good. Chalk it up to a long day but maybe it will help someone else eventually.